# Unable to create directory: /sdcard/Downloads

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am using DownloadManager class to download file and save it.

```
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
  request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"logo.jpg");
```

I am getting "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create directory: /sdcard/Download" runtime exception.

I have searched all the possible solutions and not able to get the answer.

Below is the full stack tracel .

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.architsandesara.myapplication, PID: 24246
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create directory: /sdcard/Download
at android.app.DownloadManager$Request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(DownloadManager.java:538)
at com.example.architsandesara.myapplication.fragment.DocumentsDetails$2.onClick(DocumentsDetails.java:91)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Please provide a full stack trace.

Comment: Hi jonas.koeritz,
I have updated question with stack trace.

Comment: Do you have the permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in your manifest?

Comment: Yes checked and I do have 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Then see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056109/android-runtime-error-unable-to-create-directory-on-use-of-class-downloadman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

secondary storages (like the real removable SD card) are protected by a new permission `android.permission.WRITE_MEDIA_STORAGE`, and the protection level is signatureOrSystem. one of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12853922/2615223) at stack overflow suggests this.

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22201215/2615223) answer aswell, which conveys :
From API level 19, Google has added API.

```
Context.getExternalFilesDirs()
Context.getExternalCacheDirs()
Context.getObbDirs().
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check if the external [getExternalStorageState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState()). Maybe your App is missing the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission as well.

Answer (score 0):

Set local directory like this

```
            String name = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

            name += "/YourDirectoryName/" ;
```