# Android, Xamarin: Get File Path Of SD Card

Tags: android, xamarin

I am currently working on an app, that goes through your phone and lists all available MP3 files. I managed to get this done and search for everything on the internal storage, but didnt manage to find a way using the envoirment to get to the sd card, when one is installed. This is my code - u will see a missing part when SD card is TRUE. Can you complete it?

```
    public List<string> ReturnPlayableMp3(bool sdCard)
    {
        List<string> res = new List<string>();
        string phyle;

        if(sdCard)
        {
            // missing 
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                var path1 = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.ToString();
                var mp3Files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path1, "*.mp3", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

                foreach (string currentFile in mp3Files)
                {
                    phyle = currentFile;
                    res.Add(phyle);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e9)
            {
                Toast.MakeText(ApplicationContext, "ut oh\n" + e9.Message, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            }
        }


        return res;
    }


}
```

It would need to return the exact same thing as it does for the internal storage only this time for the sd card. Right now, what is beeing returned is:

""/storage/emulated/0""

I hope you  can help me. Thank you!

SO I found the place it is: /storage/05B6-2226/

But the digits refer to only MY sd card. How do I get this path programatically?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at these methods:

- [Context.GetExternalFilesDir](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Content.Context.GetExternalFilesDir/p/System.String/)

> Returns the absolute path to the directory on the primary external
>   filesystem (that is somewhere on Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory)
>   where the application can place persistent files it owns. These files
>   are internal to the applications, and not typically visible to the
>   user as media.

- [Context.GetExternalFilesDirs](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Android.Content.Context.GetExternalFilesDirs/p/System.String/)

> Returns absolute paths to application-specific directories on all
>   external storage devices where the application can place persistent
>   files it owns. These files are internal to the application, and not
>   typically visible to the user as media.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for a couple of days with a lot of solutions that just ended up giving you the 'external' built in storage. Finally found this solution for the 'removable' SD Card and wanted to post it here in case someone else is still looking.

[How to write on external storage sd card in mashmallow in xamarin.android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48411844/how-to-write-on-external-storage-sd-card-in-mashmallow-in-xamarin-android)

Comment: While this might theoretically answer the question, it would be [much better](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Get the list of External Storage Volumes (E.g. SD Card) 
Context context = Android.App.Application.Context;
var storageManager = (Android.OS.Storage.StorageManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.StorageService);
var volumeList = (Java.Lang.Object[])storageManager.Class.GetDeclaredMethod("getVolumeList").Invoke(storageManager);

List<Java.IO.File> ExtFolders = new List<Java.IO.File>();

//Select the Directories that are not Emulated
foreach (var storage in volumeList)
{

    Java.IO.File info = (Java.IO.File)storage.Class.GetDeclaredMethod("getDirectory").Invoke(storage);
    if ((bool)storage.Class.GetDeclaredMethod("isEmulated").Invoke(storage) == false && info.TotalSpace > 0)
    {
        //Get Directory Path
        Console.WriteLine(info.Path);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanna share my answer, where I have get the extStorages Path and I use this method in my simple file browser app.

```
public static string[] GetRemovableStorages()
{
    List<string> extStorage = new List<string>();
    //If this throws exception
    string storageDir = (string)Environment.StorageDirectory;
    //Try this
    string storageDir = Directory.GetParent (Environment.ExternalStoragePublicDirectory).Parent.FullName;
    string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(storageDir);
        
    foreach(string dir in directories)
    {
        try
        {
            var extStoragePath = new Java.IO.File(dir);
            bool isRemovable = Environment.InvokeIsExternalStorageRemovable(extStoragePath);
                
            if(isRemovable) extStorage.Add(extStoragePath.AbsolutePath);
            else return null;
        }   
        catch
        {
        
        }
    }
        
    return extStorage.ToArray();
}
```

Elikill58's answer throws exception no such method "getDirectory" in my case but I recommend Elikill58's answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if anyone would still looking for an answer or not. But I came across with similar problem. where i had to fetch file paths from both external and internal storages. Here is my implementation.
basic method to get all files and from all the directories and subdirectories from file system excluding the folders we don't have access to.

```
private List<Item> GetDirectoriesAndFiles(string rootPath)
{
List<Item> result = new List<Item>();
List<Item> Files = new List<Item>();
// Get all directories and subdirectories while ignoring certain directories because android does not allow to access them.
string[] directories = Directory.GetDirectories(rootPath).Where(directory => !IgnoredDirectory().Contains(directory)).ToArray();


foreach (var directory in directories)
{
    var subDirectories = Directory.GetDirectories(directory, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    //add all subDirectories paths in results
    foreach (var subDirectory in subDirectories)
    {
        result.Add(new Item { Path = subDirectory, IsDirectory = true });
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(subDirectory);
        Files.AddRange(files.Select(x => new Item { Path = x, IsDirectory = false }));
    }
    Files.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(directory).Select(x => new Item { Path = x, IsDirectory = false }));
    result.Add(new Item { Path = directory, IsDirectory = true });
}

result.AddRange(Files);

return result;
  }




    private List<string> IgnoredDirectory()
    {
        // Add conditions to ignore specific directories because we don't have access to these folders
        // For example, ignore the "/Android/obb" directory
        return new List<string> { "/storage/emulated/0/Android" };
    }
```

Dto Class to save objects

```
public class Item
{
   public string Path { get; set; }
   public bool IsDirectory { get; set; }
}
```

Code to get available storages from android ignoring emulated

```
 List<Item> filePaths = new List<Item>();


await Task.Run(() =>
 {
     // Get all file paths from the internal storage
     filePaths = GetDirectoriesAndFiles((Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath)).ToList();
 });

 var availableStorages = GetAvaliableStorages(this);
 if (availableStorages.Any())
 {
     //because we ignored the emulated storage so we can get the first item
     // get all file paths from the external storage
     string sdCardPath = availableStorages.FirstOrDefault();
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sdCardPath))
     {
         filePaths.AddRange(GetDirectoriesAndFiles(sdCardPath));
     }
 }
```

and implementation of GetAvailableStorages()

```
 public List<string> GetAvaliableStorages(Context context)
 {
     List<string> list = null;
     try
     {

         var storageManager = (Android.OS.Storage.StorageManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.StorageService);

         var volumeList = (Java.Lang.Object[])storageManager.Class.GetDeclaredMethod("getVolumeList").Invoke(storageManager);

         list = new List<string>();

         foreach (var storage in volumeList)
         {
             Java.IO.File info = (Java.IO.File)storage.Class.GetDeclaredMethod("getPathFile").Invoke(storage);

             if (!(bool)storage.Class.GetDeclaredMethod("isEmulated").Invoke(storage) && info.TotalSpace > 0)
             {
                 list.Add(info.Path);
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {

     }
     return list;
 }
```

### Update :: Android 12 and above

```
  public List<string> GetAvaliableStorages(Context context)
  {
  List<string> list = null;
  try
  {

      var storageManager = (Android.OS.Storage.StorageManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.StorageService);

      var volumeList = (Java.Lang.Object[])storageManager.Class.GetDeclaredMethod("getVolumeList").Invoke(storageManager);

      list = new List<string>();

      foreach (var storage in volumeList)
      {
          Java.IO.File info = (Java.IO.File)storage.Class.GetDeclaredMethod("getPathFile").Invoke(storage);

          if (!(bool)storage.Class.GetDeclaredMethod("isEmulated").Invoke(storage) && info.TotalSpace > 0)
          {
              list.Add(info.Path);
          }
      }
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
      var storages = this.GetExternalFilesDirs(null);
      if (storages.Any())
      {
          //get the storage which is not emulated or self storage
          var storage = storages.FirstOrDefault(x => !x.Path.Contains(IsEmulated) && !x.Path.Contains("self"));
          // if the storage is not null then we can get the files from the external storage
          if (storage != null)
          {
              //get the base path of the storage i.e /storage/xxxxx
              var basePath = storage.Path.Split("/Android").FirstOrDefault();

              if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(basePath))
              {
                  list = new List<string> { basePath };
              }
          }
      }

  }
  return list;
 }
```

Here is the github repo link
https://github.com/usmanchaudary/AndroidStorageAccessor.git